# How to display URL parameter in WordPress Title?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the title of WordPress page dynamically according to the change in URL parameter.

For example: if the page url is domain.com/page/?key=parameter1

Page title should become "How to access parameter1"

I tried editing header.php and inserting code like this:

```
<title>How to access <?php echo $_GET['key']; ?> </title>
```

This doesn't seem to work.

**Note:** I am amateur in coding. While answering, please specify where to insert code and what to change.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't seem to work"? Do you manage to actually change the title at least?

Comment: Your coude should work. But maybe there  will be overriden from the function `wp_title()` later. Check your `header.php` for this function.

Comment: Please show some code you have in your files (you can use pre-formatted code blocks in your post)

Comment: Is this page (domain.com/page/?key=parameter1) is working properly?

Comment: Keep in mind when you do get this working you MUST escape the `$_GET` value first. You have a serious security issue with the current version